# Validate AutoMapper for type mismatches only

Tags: c#, automapper

When I use automapper, I purposely don't map a number of properties that are identical. That's one of the main reasons for me to use automapper. Outside of that, I can build a projection or class converter myself with about the same amount of code and less reflection (i.e., more performant).

The only issue I have is that we occasionally have some type mismatches. Is it possible to use automapper's configuration validation to confirm that the types are interchangeable?
I know that for some types, like string to int, that can't be validated 100% because someone could use a string that isn't convertible to an integer. But some types like timespan to datetime are not convertible without an explicit map. I would like to call those out. The existing `AssertConfigurationIsValid()` method fails to satisfy my needs because of the strict combination of explicit mapping/ignoring needed for it to only ever complain about type mismatches instead.

Comment: Do you mean the `AssertConfigurationIsValid()` method?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I typed this from my phone and didn't have the name handy. But I left it a little open because if that one is only intended to check for missing members, I'd like to use anything that'd simply check to see if the type conversions are compatible.

Comment: Then it is not clear what the problem is. Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of the problem you have. Add example classes and mappings to show the problem you have. Also explain why `AssertConfigurationIsValid()` will not help in these situations.

Comment: I disagree. I gave a very clear example of why that method validates things I don't care for and what I am attempting to validate. You might want to reread.

Comment: You can use `MemberList.None` and add your custom validation through an extension point.

Comment: Got it. So there's nothing built-in that'd determine if the types are compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported by the library. One possible solution is to write our own validation process that only checks the source and destination type with some variation of casts and try/catching Convert.ChangeType().